# Explicit instantiation of a class with concept'ed methods

Tags: c++

Look at this code:

```
#include <concepts>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void op();
};

struct B
{
    void op( bool );
};

template<typename T>
concept concept_C = is_same<T, A>::value || is_same<T, B>::value;

template<typename T>
    requires concept_C<T>
struct C
{
    void opA()
        requires is_same<T, A>::value;
    void opB( bool f )
        requires is_same<T, B>::value;
    T *pt;
};

template<typename T>
    requires concept_C<T>
void C<T>::opA()
    requires is_same<T, A>::value
{
    pt->op();
}

template<typename T>
    requires concept_C<T>
void C<T>::opB( bool f )
    requires is_same<T, B>::value
{
    pt->op( f );
}

template
struct C<A>;

template
struct C<B>;
```

MSVC will instantiate opA for A as well as B and opB also for A as well as B and gives the following errors:

```
(42,10): error : too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
(46,8): message : in instantiation of member function 'C<A>::opB' requested here
(7,7): message : 'op' declared here
(34,9): error : too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0
(49,8): message : in instantiation of member function 'C<B>::opA' requested here
(12,7): message : 'op' declared here
```

clang gives similar errors, but g++12 is smarter and skips inappropriate compilation, i.e. filters the functions through their concepts, i.e. it compiles opA only for A and opB only for B - so which compiler is right here ? And is there a workaround ?

[EDIT]: Hey folks, I'm editing this post the same day and I've updated Visual Studio to the latest official version through the installer. And the good news is: this bug has been fixed and the code is now compiled properly. And although clang in Visual Studio has been updated to 12.0 it still has the same incapability.

Answer (score 2):

Seems GCC is the correct one of the three.

> **[temp.explicit]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.explicit#11) **An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members** (not including members inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, **provided that the associated constraints, if any, of that member are satisfied by the template arguments of the explicit instantiation** ([temp.constr.decl], [temp.constr.constr]), except as described below.

So the definition is only meant to be instantiated *provided* that the associated constraints (which include `is_same<T, A>::value`) are satisfied. Clearly that is not the case, so MSVC and Clang are wrong.

As a workaround, you can repeat the condition in an `if constexpr`.

```
template<typename T>
    requires concept_C<T>
void C<T>::opA()
    requires is_same<T, A>::value
{
    if constexpr (is_same<T, A>::value)
        pt->op();
}
```

Comment: @BonitaMontero - If this answered your question, you might want to mark this answer as accepted (by clicking the gray check button on the left).

Answer (score 0):

This code should compile. It was fixed in gcc itself only very recently (10.3 or 11.1 and upwards). This issue in gcc's tracker contains more information: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96164.

It's tracked in clang as https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46684.